# How can I produce a matrix?

Tags: matlab

How can I produce a matrix like `a` and `b` in MATLAB? I put `a` and `b` as below. For example, `a` has 88 columns; how I can just write 88 instead of typing 1, 88 times?

```
a=[1 1 1 1 1 1....]
b=[1
   1
   1
   1
   1
   .
   .
   .]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [***`ones`***](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ones.html)

```
>> n = 1;
>> a = n * ones(1,88)

a =

     1     1     1     1     1 ...

>> b= n* ones(88,1)

b =

     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
 ...
```

Comment: What about for an arbitrary value? (Say, 2)